PDF Blend modes renders differently across browsers
I am building a PDF graphics image on the fly, which uses some of the standard PDF blending modes, for example "Screen".
However, when I open the file in Illustrator or Acrobat, they looks similar but much different than viewing the same exact file in browsers (FF or Edge or Chrome). I understand different browsers may handle it differently, but I would like to achieve the same result across all browsers and PDF reader and Illustrator (what suppose to be the purpose of PDF).
Here is the PDF content:
% General blending for the page:
15 0 obj
<< /Type /ExtGState
  /BM /Screen
>>
endobj

% My Pattern Graphics State:
16 0 obj
<< /Type /ExtGState
  /CA 0.500
  /ca 0.500
>>
endobj

% My pattern consists of 3 red circles, color set with CMYK mode
17 0 obj
<< /Type /Pattern
  /Length 744
  /PatternType 1
  /TilingType 1
  /XStep 141.73228346456693
  /YStep 141.73228346456693
  /BBox [0 0 200 200]
  /PaintType 1
  /Resources <<
    /ExtGState <<
      /G3n7jpt02prtn 16 0 R
    >>
  >>
>>
stream
/G3n7jpt02prtn gs
0.000 1.000 1.000 0.000 k
120 80 m 119.768 96.473 108.284 108.284 y 96.473 119.768 80 120 y 63.527 119.768 51.716 108.284 y 40.232 96.473 40 80 y 40.232 63.527 51.716 51.716 y 63.527 40.232 80 40 y 96.473 40.232 108.284 51.716 y 119.768 63.527 120 80 y f
100 120 m 99.768 136.473 88.284 148.284 y 76.473 159.768 60 160 y 43.527 159.768 31.716 148.284 y 20.232 136.473 20 120 y 20.232 103.527 31.716 91.716 y 43.527 80.232 60 80 y 76.473 80.232 88.284 91.716 y 99.768 103.527 100 120 y f
140 120 m 139.768 136.473 128.284 148.284 y 116.473 159.768 100 160 y 83.527 159.768 71.716 148.284 y 60.232 136.473 60 120 y 60.232 103.527 71.716 91.716 y 83.527 80.232 100 80 y 116.473 80.232 128.284 91.716 y 139.768 103.527 140 120 y f
endstream
endobj

% The page content, which fills the page with the above pattern and shows on top 3 more green circles with the screen blending:
18 0 obj
<</Type /Page
  /Parent 1 0 R
  /Resources 2 0 R
  /Contents 19 0 R>>
endobj
19 0 obj
<</Length 832>>
stream
2.835 0 0 2.835 0 0 cm
/Pattern cs
/Ps0gpdo03xmd2 scn
0 0 m 400 0 l 400 400 l 0 400 l f
/Gme179iqab6jw gs
1.000 0.000 1.000 0.498 k
120 80 m 119.768 96.473 108.284 108.284 y 96.473 119.768 80 120 y 63.527 119.768 51.716 108.284 y 40.232 96.473 40 80 y 40.232 63.527 51.716 51.716 y 63.527 40.232 80 40 y 96.473 40.232 108.284 51.716 y 119.768 63.527 120 80 y f
100 120 m 99.768 136.473 88.284 148.284 y 76.473 159.768 60 160 y 43.527 159.768 31.716 148.284 y 20.232 136.473 20 120 y 20.232 103.527 31.716 91.716 y 43.527 80.232 60 80 y 76.473 80.232 88.284 91.716 y 99.768 103.527 100 120 y f
140 120 m 139.768 136.473 128.284 148.284 y 116.473 159.768 100 160 y 83.527 159.768 71.716 148.284 y 60.232 136.473 60 120 y 60.232 103.527 71.716 91.716 y 83.527 80.232 100 80 y 116.473 80.232 128.284 91.716 y 139.768 103.527 140 120 y f
endstream
endobj

% General resources for all document:
2 0 obj
<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
  /Font << /F1 3 0 R >>
  /ExtGState <<
    /Gme179iqab6jw 15 0 R
  >>
  /Pattern <<
    /Ps0gpdo03xmd2 17 0 R
  >>
>>
endobj

% General document settings:
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [
  18 0 R
]
/Count 1
  /MediaBox [0 0 1133.86 1133.86] % = 400x400 mm
>>
endobj

% Root:
21 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 1 0 R
  /OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]
  /PageLayout /OneColumn
>>
endobj

This is the desired result (in Illustrator and Adobe PDF reader):

But this is how it looks like in FF/Edge:

And this is how it looks like in Chrome:

Am I missing some definition in my PDF?
Note: I am using PDF-1.6 specification.
Link to the PDF file itself:
Test PDF file
EDIT:
I've tried to add a Transparent Group, but seems I am still missing something as it gives no difference. Test PDF file 2
Thanks a lot

hi, can you clarify what you want to achieve? You have provided useful infos, but we are missing the issue, question, or what you want to achieve. Are you asking "am I missing some definition in my PDF", because when you open the said PDF in browser, it views differently than in Illustrator/Acrobat?

Yes, exactly. I want to achieve the same result across all browsers, and the same as in PDF and Illustrator.

Clearly there are bugs in the implementation(s) used by the browsers, which is very likely; historically the PDF engines used by browsers have been of poor quality. I believe Firefox have improved recently but your evidence is that they still have some way to go. Since you cannot control bugs in the PDF consumer, your only other option is to reduce the complexity of your PDF as much as possible. If you render the content to an image, then you will very likely get the same result in all browsers. Of course the file will be larger.... Alternatively open a bug report with the maintainers.

FWIW I should point out that with my Acrobat Professional the result is the same as your Firefox/Edge result and does not match your posted Acrobat result. This appears to be because you have not specified the colour space in a group at the page level, so the consumer performs the blending in whatever is the current space for the device. If I set it to RGB I get the Firefox output, if I set it to CMYK I get your Acrobat output.  Try adding a Transparency Group object with a /CS to the page. Finally the xref table in your file seems to be incorrect.

I've tried to set /CS in page group, still the same result.... How is my xref table incorrect....? Thank you

The end of your test2 file has startxref followed by binary 0x2f 0x12, the xref token begins at offset 0x122f in your file. The statxref token is supposed to be followed by the offset (in bytes from the start of the file) of the xref table, as an ascii string, so should be '4655'. Your first file has the same problem. If you can't follow what I mean open your file in an editor, look for the startxref token, compare it with say Example 3.7 on page 98 of the 1.7 PDF Reference.

Now that you have a CS in the group your file renders the same for me in RGB and CMYK devices. Chrome does indeed still render it incorrectly, this is clearly a bug in Chrome (web browsers are not good at rendering PDF files). You can't reasonably expect the specification to deal with broken implementations. Since this is a bug in Chrome you should start by reporting it as a bug to the project maintainers. You can then either wait until they fix it, or fall back to using an image, which as I said above is about the only reasonably reliable way of getting consistent rendering.

In comments you asked how to tell an XREF is incorrect, and the simplest way is close the file in Acrobat Reader. IF it has adjusted the file contents to view it, then it will ask do you want to save the edits (Reader is a very small subset of Pro, but it is an editor just the same, just with significantly less functions)

As to the main question why does Acrobat look different to other viewers is because it is Adobes Format ! Thus other viewers try to stick to the wooly ISO standard they were given, but Adobe did not have to open source their code. (several Adobe methods vary compared to the ISO-norm)
We can see from Acrobat Reader above that it too can follow everybody else's desktop viewers way of viewing a RGB screen for printout.

So ensuring all browsers etc are running in same session on same screen hardware.
Taking your second file in and out of Acrobat Reader we can say it is per Adobes viewer standards see top left. So background blending is not a problem as there is none. But we see top centre that many other editors and viewers treat the content blending differently. This is related to browsers but simply that the majority of browsers are Chromium/PDFium based (Chrome and Opera Lower left). Except Edge which are the 3 on the right.

Why are the 3 Edge views different is because Edge uses Acrobat Active X at top and Powered by Acrobat at the bottom but the one in the middle is most common Chromium/PDFium !! We can thus suggest Chromium's apart from Edge have a serious problem and then there is a secondary Firefox and Edge issue presenting a different most common blend.
